# Custom list button throwing 'Insufficient privilege' when clicked on by user other than System admin profile

Tags: related-list, url, list-button, insufficient-privileges

I have a custom list button on a related list under opportunity.On click of the list button, it takes me to a VF page. This works fine for the system admin, but when logged in as a user with non-system admin profile, it throws the following error.

> *Insufficient Privileges You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of
>   the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more
>   information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.  Click here to return
>   to the previous page*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make this Visualforce page available for your Profile you see this error on. Follow the steps below in Salesforce Classic.

1. Setup > Manage Users > **Profiles**
2. Scroll to the Profile you see this error on and click on the **Profile Name**
3. In the **Enabled Visualforce Page Access** section, click **Edit**.
4. Find your Visualforce page within the **Available Visualforce Pages** section and move it to **Enabled Visualforce Pages**.
5. **Retest** your button.

Comment: @Sowparnika Please mark this as a correct answer so others can benefit from the valid information provided.

Comment: For the same user, even the trigger is not firing. All the handlers and utilities pertaining to the trigger are given the permission as per u had mentioned,but trigger doesn't work.Could you pls help me out? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I would advise you to create a new Question for your current issue regarding the trigger. Provide you trigger code and other information needed for the community to give you a best answer.